# Wrapper role in decorators: why return wrapper and not call it?

Tags: python, function, return, wrapper, python-decorators

There are similar questions here but I couldn't find anything answering clearly exactly what my question is. I don't understand why the two blocks of code below behave in the ways that they do.

So the following code prints whenever the file is run (note: I had "is saved" here before but a comment below corrected me):

```
def outerFunction(function):
    def wrapper():
        function()
        print('wrapper')
    wrapper()
    
@outerFunction
def innerFunction():
    print('innerFunction')
    return
```

But the following code needs to have the inner function called in order to print:

```
def outerFunction(function):
    def wrapper():
        function()
        print('wrapper')
    return wrapper
    
@outerFunction
def innerFunction():
    print('innerFunction')
    return

innerFunction()
```

What I've tried in order to understand better: following tutorials, reading posts here, tinkering with code.

I understand that the outer function is called automatically when it is declared as a decorator and that **return wrapper** is how it is done, so with my level of understanding, I can write decorators and make them work, but obviously doing that without understanding them well isn't ideal. I'm having trouble understanding what the difference is between **wrapper()** and **return wrapper**.

Comment: How does your file print something when it's saved? Or do you mean when you execute it?

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami Yeah I mean when I execute it. I was writing it on a website that lets you write client side Python and I confused saving it with running it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Decorator syntax is a shortcut for function application. The decorator is called *immediately* after the decorated `def` statement is executed, with

```
@outerFunction
def innerFunction():
    print('innerFunction')
    return
```

being exactly equivalent (aside from some apparent implementation-specific optimizations to reduce the number load/store operations) to

```
def innerFunction():
    print('innerFunction')
    return

innerFunction = outerFunction(innerFunction)
```

In the first case, you no longer have a function bound to `innerFunction`; you executed it immediately when `outerFunction` was executed, then bound the value `None` to the name `innerFunction`.

In the second case, `innerFunction` is bound to the wrapper itself, which will call (each time *it* is called) the original `innerFunction`.